# bash listing subfolders in current folder doesn't give expected results [gives only first folder]

Tags: linux, bash

I try to list subfolders and save them as list to a variable

```
DIRS=($(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ))
```

After that I want to do some work in subfolders. i.e.

```
for item in $DIRS
 do     
echo $item
```

But  after

```
echo $DIRS
```

it gives  only first item (subfolder). Could someone point me to error or propose another solution?

Comment: try quoting both variables as well. echoing an unquoted $DIR will strip the newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates a bash array but lists only one of three subdirectories:

```
$ dirs=($(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ))
$ echo $dirs
./subdir2
```

To see all the directories, you must use the `[@]` or `[*]` subscript form:

```
$ echo "${dirs[@]}"
./subdir2 ./subdir1 ./subdir3
```

Or, using it in a loop:

```
$ for item in "${dirs[@]}"; do echo $item; done
./subdir2
./subdir1
./subdir3
```

#### Avoiding problems from word splitting

Note that, in the code above, the shell performs word splitting before the array is created.  Thus, this approach will fail if any subdirectories have whitespace in their names.

1. The following will successfully create an array of subdirectory names even if the names have spaces, tabs or newlines in them:

   ```
   dirs=(*/)
   ```
2. If you need to use `find` and you want it to be safe for difficult file names, then use find's `--exec` option.

#### Documentation

The form `$dirs` returns just the first element of the array.  This is documented in `man bash`:

> Referencing an array variable without a  subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0.

The use of `[@]` and `[*]` is also documented in `man bash`:

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with pathname expansion. If subscript is @ or *, the word expands to all members of  name.  These  subscripts differ  only when the word appears within double quotes.  If the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS  special  variable, and  ${name[@]}  expands  each element of name to a separate word.